# Idle - Unable to open raster file - : Success

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

When attempting to print to a Dymo Labelwriter 450, I get this error:

```
Idle - Unable to open raster file - : Success
```

I can print a test page and from the command line, but not from any print dialog. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This problem appears to be connected to this GTK bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/998156

The bug was reported almost two years ago. It has not yet been fixed and it's unclear when, if ever, it will be fixed.

In the interim, one ingenious user from the Netherlands found a workaround: use Print Preview and then print from the Print Preview window.

Source: http://forum.ubuntu-nl.org/hardware-en-drivers/inactief-unable-to-open-raster-file-success/

Answer (score 0):

In my case ( as you can see in cups error_log: https://goo.gl/a8lBrQ ) printing `lp -oraw -d <printername> <filename>` helped for sharing Dymo 450 LabelWriter printer via network.

(ref: advice taken from https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=111148&p=762834 and project I used advice in https://goo.gl/QCqrOj )

Answer (score 0):

For me this was because I was trying to print an 8.5x11 layout to a 1-up label printer.  I needed to change the page layout, which had been previously changed from another label run.  The bug linked here linked to another bug in hplip, which had a suggestion for Inkscape, but this made sense for glabel which I was using, and sure enough that was the problem.  Essentially it is sending a pagesize attribute to the rasterizer that the rasterizer can't handle.