# I need to install DYMO software for labelwriter 450, but i can't... any help?

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

i can't find how to install and use the labelwriter 450 and it's urgent. i print for my job 50 to 100 labels per week.

i don't know what to do, i just went to ubuntu from windows 8.1.1.

I tried with wine but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the correct drivers for CUPS, the Linux printing system.
As far as I can tell, you can download them here:

https://dymo.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/101/~/dymo-drivers-and-downloads#lw_linux

Comment: you may also find the discussion here useful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=861781

Comment: CUPS driver installation could not be enough:  "The printer setup requires an appropriate PostScript Printer Definition (PPD) file. Unfortunately, this seems not to be part of the installation package. For this reason, we need to download the CUPS driver provided by Dymo. This is currently version 1.4.0, which can be downloaded here. Afterwards the archive needs to be extracted. The model file is part of it and should be copied to the default model folder of CUPS." quote from https://www.baitando.com/it/2017/12/12/install-dymo-labelwriter-on-headless-linux where there are all the needed steps

Answer (score 11):

### 14.04 and later

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-dymo
```

Comment: Worked perfectly to recognize and print from a Dymo LabelWriter 400 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: and then how do you open it?

Answer (score 10):

To install Dymo 450 LabelWriter on Debian Systems - Ubuntu, Raspibian, you might need first:  (helped me to compile drivers, advice from : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1502581 )

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev libcupsimage2-dev gcc g++
```

Then you want to do install dymo linux sdk (both links work at 2016-05-14):

- http://www.dymo.com/en-US/dymo-label-sdk-and-cups-drivers-for-linux-dymo-label-sdk-cups-linux-p--1
- http://var.dymo.com/US/resources/sdk/linux/

Then you unpack it, compile and install driver:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Later I've added driver via cups web interface like any other driver, choosing right ppd file. (example project : https://www.hmazter.com/2013/05/raspberry-pi-printer-server-for-labelwriter and another: https://gist.github.com/gwpl/6d6c1457b4d1f6b778917a2f7c3c57fd ).

Finally, I **share via network** Dymo 450 LabelWriter(s) attached to Ubuntu and Raspibian with other Linuxes (including Archlinux) and I've found that to make printing via network (e.g. ipp:// and ipps:// ) to work, I need to schedule printing (of pdf, png, whatever) add `-o raw` to lpr command. You will see example of **`-o raw`** in https://gist.github.com/gwpl/6d6c1457b4d1f6b778917a2f7c3c57fd and https://askubuntu.com/a/748035/31300 .

Finally references for installing and using Dymo 450 under Linux:

- https://www.hmazter.com/2013/05/raspberry-pi-printer-server-for-labelwriter
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=861781&page=6
- http://www.taklischris.info/varietas/use-your-dymo-printer-on-ubuntu

Comment: Sadz, the links have stopped working in 2018

Comment: Which links? As I checked they seem working. I've just downloaded dymo cups drivers package, I see tutorials.

Comment: http://var.dymo.com/US/resources/sdk/linux/ is no longer pointing to the SDK/CUPS but the first one is (at this point ;-) )

Answer (score 4):

The answer by Grzegorz kinda works, but there is an issue in the official DYMO sources which prevents it from building on the latest version of CUPS. I found a patch on [this Ubuntu forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376862&styleid=117) which contains the fix for it.

The post's instructions were:

```
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/dymo-cups-drivers.git

Then copy that files inside the folder of driver, and finally:
* patch -Np1 -i cups-ppd-header.patch
* ./configure
* make
* sudo make install
```

Basically, several files are missing this line, which makes it impossible to build:

```
#include <cups/ppd.h>
```

I made the change against the official version 1.4.0.5 copy of the source and put it in a repository for others to use:
https://github.com/Kyle-Falconer/DYMO-SDK-for-Linux

Comment: Wait, but that link is from arch linux. This is an Ubuntu forum; how does that work?

Comment: @LimitedAtonement It works just fine because in the end you have to compile the program with `make`, I've been using it on Ubuntu and Raspbian. The easiest way to get the drivers working are to [use the copy on my github](https://github.com/Kyle-Falconer/DYMO-SDK-for-Linux). Let me know if you run into issues.

Comment: Forwarded from [MousyBusiness](https://askubuntu.com/users/947956/mousybusiness): Kyle Falconers github repo is the solution for me. It seems there are several missing files which he has corrected

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI: If you need a label printer, do not buy a DYMO from this point in time onwards.

I have contacted their customer support and although not properly mentioned on their website, they have stopped supporting Linux as of this point in time.

Comment: They have a "if it works, it works, but if it fails, we won't fix it", policy with respect to the Labelwriter 450. That's what fuels the printer-driver-dymo package. 
For the other Dymo (the part I can see doesn't have a model nr), we have contacted them and got he "you're on your own" reply....

Comment: Any alternatives?

Comment: No, I don't know. I bought a ZJ9200 that advertized: "with Linux support". That statement was a mistake. They pointed me to android drivers and stuff like that. (Android is linux, right? ... In a way, yes, but not really....) 
I've made a driver for that myself. It is in a "works for me" state. Not yet a CUPS driver where it is integrated into the printing system.